# Алгоритм соотношения картинок с артикулами

Tags: php, laravel, изображения

Вопрос касательно алгоритмизации.
Пишу интернет-магазин. Есть база картинок, названия которых связаны с артикулами следующим образом:
артикул_параметр.jpg

Например:

- ЭП-300-1500C_v1.jpg
- ЭП-300-1500C_v2.jpg
- ЭП-300-1500C_v3.jpg
- ЭП-300-1500C_v4.jpg

И т.д.

Написал алгоритм, который:

1. Берёт из базы артикул;
2. Ищет соответствия с артикулом в базе картинок с помощью `strpos()`;
3. Собирает всё в массив;
4. Обновляет запись в базе.

Проблема в том, что когда в названиях артикулов есть одинаковые символы, он приписывает картинку туда, куда не нужно. Например как с артикулами

ЭП-300-1500C_v1 и 300-1500C.

Как избежать этого?

Comment: Лучше добавить код, чтобы легче было было разобраться где ошибка или недоработка и исправить это

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему следующим образом:

```
if(substr($file, 0, strlen($article))==$article){
                $filePath = 'products\jpg\\'.$file;
                $newArr[] = $filePath;
 }
```

То есть, отрезал от названия картинки количество символов так, чтобы по длине они совпадали с артикулом. Потом сравнил получившуюся строку с самим артикулом. Если true, значит картинка добавляется в массив. Иначе, пропускается.